# Cucumber test failed first time build in Jenkins but when run build multiple times build get pass

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber-java

I am using a cucumber test with multiple features file for testing spring boot project, test run locally passed and when go to Jenkin build it gets failed but when I am trying multiple time build(3-4 times) its get succeed and build pass without doing any changes.
I don't understand what wrong I am doing is there any data related problem or Jenkin configuration problem or multiple feature file problems.
please guide what I am missing?

Comment: Any error logs and configuration? It would help if we could see and possibly reproduce the issue.

Comment: inside a log, Cucumber test get fail with an assertion error

Comment: then I guess you should investigate why the assertions fails.

Comment: There is some data problem in cucumber scenario. Thanks for the help!